# object constructor pointing to Object function after redefining prototype of self defined function

Tags: javascript, prototype

Whenever i redefined prototype of function and create an new object of it, its constructor starts pointing to the root Object function instead of the function itself. Let me explain it with scenario:

```
var Person=function(firstName,lastName)
{
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
} 

Person.prototype.getFullName=function()
{
    return this.firstName+" "+this.lastName;
}
var student=new Person("Ankur","Aggarwal");
student.constructor //shows Person which is correct
```

After that if I redefined the Person prototype and create a new object of the changed

```
Person.prototype={}
var manager=new Person('John','Smith');
manager.constructor // Points to Object. Why?
```

Also if it is pointing to the Object not Person, how come it has the access to the Person properties like firstName and lastName?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given the constructor:

```
var Person=function(firstName,lastName)
{
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
}
```

It has a default *prototype* property that is an object whose *constructor* property references the *Person* constructor. It is this property that (by default) instances inherit through the `[[Prototype]]` chain.

When you create an instance, the *firstName* and *lastName* properties are defined on the instance, as if by:

```
var person = {firstName:..., lastName:...};
```

so access to those properties is unaffected by the constructor's prototype.

When a new Object is assigned to the constructor's prototype:

```
Person.prototype = {};
```

it inherits a *constructor* property from *Object.prototype* (which is its constructor). So accessing an instance's *constructor* first looks on the instance, then on its `[[Prototype]]` (Person.prototype), then on its `[[Prototype]]` (Object.prototype) and finds a reference to *Object*. You can fix that by doing:

```
Person.prototype.constructor = Person;
```

You can find more information on MDN: [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Answer (score 2):

Constructing an object does not set its `constructor` property to the function that constructed it. Instead, a function's default `prototype` is initialized with a `constructor` property pointing to that function, and objects constructed by that function inherit the `constructor` property from the prototype.

When you replace the function's `prototype`, the replacement does not automatically get that function assigned to its `constructor` property. Instead, the new `prototype` inherits `constructor` from *its* prototype, which is `Object.prototype`. Thus, objects created by the function will now inherit a `constructor` of `Object` from their grandprototype, `Object.prototype`.